# How to let OpenCl see intel and nvidia devices?

Tags: opencl, gpu, intel, nvidia

I wonder how we can have OpenCl "seeing" my K20. Xeon, and Xeon Phi at the same time?

Especially I'm confused about the use of two libraries here (from NVidia and Intel).

How to do it, if possible at all?

Answer (score 5):

The OpenCL Installable Client Driver (ICD) takes care of this for you. It is the same regardless of whose implementation you have installed, and exposes all implementations as separate OpenCL "Platforms".

When you call **clGetPlatformIDs** it will tell you how many platforms you have installed. There could be one for AMD, one for NVIDIA, and one for Intel, for example.

Then within each platform you call **clGetDeviceIDs** which will return the number of devices within that platform. On your NVIDIA platform you'll find your K20, and within your Intel platform you'll find your Xeon CPU and Xeon Phi co-processor.

If you build or download the **clInfo** utility you'll see a nice dump of all the installed platforms and devices and the capabilities of each.

Comment: Thanks, I have written such program for my self. the point is before OpenCl was able to see all my platforms and since I updated the Intel compiler, nvidia does not show up anymore.

Comment: Re-install the NVIDIA driver then. It sounds like the Phi driver may have overwritten the ICD or (horrors) doesn't use ICD.

Comment: Updating any platform's driver should not ever cause such a problem, so please report this bug to Intel.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved.
Looking at the key directory:

```
/etc/OpenCL/vendors/*.icd
```

I noticed that for Nvidia the library in used was a link which was duplicated in difference places and pointing to two different releases.
I just replace the former one by the most recent one, the one I've installed recently, and here we go.
Opencl did not know which one to use I guess.
It's like the installation location has changed between the two nividia versions.
When I was supposed to have removed it before reinstalling that  was actually not true.
Thank you all for your hell.

Comment: I was looking for a solution to this problem but I laugh a little with your "Thank you all for your hell." =). Anyway. Thanks for sharing this solution